# Avoiding redirect server's url to www for specific url path

Tags: apache-2.4, redirect, android

I want to enable auto-verification of deep links in Android for which I need to host the file `assetlinks.json` on my server `https://mycompany.com`. This will allow auto-verification of my deep links when the app is installed. The problem is, we have redirect setup such that all requests from `https://mycompany.com` go to `https://www.mycompany.com`. As a result, when I put the file in the `.well-known` folder, it gets hosted on `https://www.mycompany.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json` which does not satisfy the requirement for Android's domain validator.

See domain non-redirect section here
https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/10710301?sjid=18198349224505489730-NA

So if I try to open the url `https://mycompany.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json` it gets redirected to `https://www.mycompany.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json` and the file shows up in the broswer, so opening the url in browser is not a good test. Rather, I can use `curl` command in the terminal to find out whats going wrong.

`curl https://www.mycompany.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json` will return with contents of the file but `curl https://mycompany.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json` will not.

I am seeing other companies being able to do that like say, Lyft.

When we execute the command `curl https://lyft.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json` in terminal, you can see they host the file correctly on their server without the `www` regardless of having a redirect in place for other url links, so if we put `https://lyft.com` it is still getting redirected to `https://www.lyft.com` correctly.

How do we acheive this? How can we keep the redirect and still put an exception for one such url path that has assetlinks.json in the end?

My company website is hosted on Apache HTTP server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache Conditional Redirect HTTP to HTTPS](https://serverfault.com/questions/898917/apache-conditional-redirect-http-to-https)